# Not letting me create an empty file with file_put_contents

Tags: php, arrays, pipeline

I have an automated scheduling job that runs daily.

```
$i = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
  file_put_contents('outfile.txt', $array1[$i]."\t".$array2[$i]);
}
```

However on some days `$array1` is empty.  When it's empty, `file_put_contents` doesn't generate a file at all and breaks my entire scheduled pipeline job.  How can I make it so that `file_put_contents` will still generate a empty outfile.txt as part of my pipeline?

Comment: `if(empty($array1)){...}`

Comment: is this before the for loop?

Comment: Instead of `file_put_contents` try `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`.

Comment: its a step for the logic, you still need to fill the the ...

Comment: WAIT! Each loop cycle will overwrite the `outfile.txt`. Are you sure?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor good catch! gonna add FILE_APPEND

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned throw this in an if statement for empty and you're good to go.

```
if(empty($array1)){ 
    file_put_contents(
        'outfile.txt', 
        '' //contents for outfile when array is empty
    );
}else{ 
    $i = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
        file_put_contents('outfile.txt', $array1[$i]."\t".$array2[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: missing a close parenthesis ) in if statement